# How to change default message "Please enter a value with a valid mimetype." for HTML file input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I just came across the `accept` attribute of `<input type="file">` and i really like it as i see that i don't need to write seperate validation for input file type if i use this attribute. its very simple like

`<input type="file" accept="image/*">` will accept only image files..

`<input type="file" accept="audio/*">` will accept only audio files..

`<input type="file" accept="video/*">` will accept only video files..

However i see that if i some how select a different file then i see an error message

`Please enter a value with a valid mimetype.`

i just want to know if it i can somehow change this error message and print it so something of my choice.. also is it possible to add some css to this error message ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using  a little bit of JavaScript magic (mark the `oninvalid` attribute):

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please, blah, blah, blah ')"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

This working using jquery validator:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-accept="Your message" />
```